# Docker containers can't see moved files in shared directory

Tags: php, docker, file, nginx, file-permissions

I have WordPress on a Docker setup with Nginx and PHP-FPM in separate containers. Both share a mounted volume, both both are running under a user `wp` with the same ID and GID. Everything works fine, apart from this baffling issue I get when the PHP container moves files.

I've made a PHP script that imports images into my site. On the host, as user `administrator`, I copy the files I want to import into an `inbox` folder, then run the script on the PHP container via the browser. The import moves JPEGs from `inbox` to another folder in the same volume, `images`. Afterwards, the shell on neither the PHP nor Nginx container can see the file (although weirdly they know the file's name), and trying to view the image in the browser pretty consistently results in a 404, apart from maybe one or two intermittent successful requests.

The inbox folder before import, from the host:

```
.rw-r--r--@ 3.7M administrator 30 Apr  8:19 trees-upwards.jpg
```

From the PHP container:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 wp      wp        3651651 Apr 30 07:19 trees-upwards.jpg
```

From the Nginx container:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 wp      wp        3651651 Apr 30 07:19 trees-upwards.jpg
```

I can see the image in my browser when I visit the URL ending `uploads/inbox/trees-upwards.jpg`.

The destination folder after import, from the host:

```
.rw-r--r--@ 3.7M administrator 30 Apr  8:19 trees-upwards.jpg
```

From the PHP container:

```
ls: images/trees-upwards.jpg: No such file or directory
```

From the Nginx container:

```
ls: images/trees-upwards.jpg: No such file or directory
```

When I try to view the image at `uploads/images/trees-upwards.jpg` I get an initial sight of it, but when I refresh, consistently 404.

- I've tried setting the owner and group of the images in the host to the same ID and GID as `wp` before running the script, but I get the same result.
- I've also tried moving the files using `shell_exec( "mv $path $new_path" );` instead of `rename`.
- I've also tried `shell_exec( "chown wp:wp $path; mv $path $new_path );"`.
- Uploading images via the WordPress media library upload page works fine.

All the script does is move the files using `rename` – it doesn't make any changes to the owner or permissions.

Has anyone come across this kind of problem before?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way I was moving the file. I checked to see how WordPress does it: in the `_wp_handle_upload` function it uses to move uploaded files to the upload folder there is this bit:

```php
if ( 'wp_handle_upload' === $action ) {
    $move_new_file = @move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $new_file );
} else {
    // Use copy and unlink because rename breaks streams.
    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.NoSilencedErrors.Discouraged
    $move_new_file = @copy( $file['tmp_name'], $new_file );
    unlink( $file['tmp_name'] );
}
```

When I change my PHP code to first copy, then delete the original file

```php
@copy( $path, $new_path );
unlink( $path );
```

Everything works fine. I don't know how streams work. I did read somewhere that `rename` doesn't work properly on older versions of PHP, but I'm running 7.4. I'm just glad I found a method that achieves what I want. Hope this helps somebody else!